# index out of range error in c#, "Cannot find column 0"

Tags: c#, closedxml

This is a snippet of my code.

```
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
GridView[] gvExcel = new GridView[] { gv01PL, gv01PD, gv01T1, gv023P, gv023L, gv02SU };
string[] name = new string[] { "01-PL", "01-PD", "01-T1", "02-3P", "02-3L", "02-SU" };
for (int i = 0; i < gvExcel.Length; i++)//each gridview
{
    if (gvExcel[i].Visible)
    {
        gvExcel[i].AllowPaging = false;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(name[i].ToString());
        for (int z = 0; z < gvExcel[i].Columns.Count; z++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(gvExcel[i].Columns[z].HeaderText);
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvExcel[i].Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            for (int c = 0; c < row.Cells.Count; c++)
            {
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][c] = row.Cells[c].Text;
            }
        }
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
        gvExcel[i].AllowPaging = true;
    }
}
```

I am having trouble with this line:

```
dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][c] = row.Cells[c].Text;
```

It is giving the error of "Cannot find column 0". I know I am missing something simple here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not all indexes start at 0, maybe try to initialize c to 1 instead of 0 in second for loop. Would probably need to use c <= cellCount as well

Comment: @ComplexityAdverse I tried that and now it gives the error "Cannot find column 1"

Comment: Maybe the dt.Rows.Add() method is generating a row of 0 size, I cant see anything that would tell the machine how big that row should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be getting this error because the `DataTable` doesn't have any columns.

Make sure that this `gvExcel[i].Columns.Count` isn't 0 here:

> ```
>    for (int z = 0; z < gvExcel[i].Columns.Count; z++)
>    {
>        dt.Columns.Add(gvExcel[i].Columns[z].HeaderText);
>    }
> ```

Comment: it is indeed 0. but I don't know why. I will keep looking into this

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that :)

Comment: I had to turn off autogeneratcolumns and make a header for each column for each gridview but it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Clone your row instead...

```
var desRow = dt.NewRow();
var sourceRow = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1];
desRow.ItemArray = sourceRow.ItemArray.Clone() as object[];

dt.Rows.Add(desRow);
```